# How can I use RealmResult loaded from background thread and use it in Android Main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

In my app I am using `ViewModel`, and I want to keep Realm instance and all the CRUD operations in background thread. The `ViewModel` has a `MutableLiveData`:

```
data class User(val userId: Long, val name: String) : RealmModel

class UserViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val realmThreadContext = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

    lateinit var realm: Realm

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(realmThreadContext) {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        }
    }

    val users: MutableLiveData<RealmResults<User>> = MutableLiveData()

    suspend fun loadData() {
        withContext(realmThreadContext) {
            users.postValue(realm.where(User::class.java).findAll())
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        realm.close()
    }
}
```

```
class UserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: UserViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.users.observe(this, Observer { users ->
            tv_user_names.text = users.joinToString(", ") { it.name }
        })

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.loadData()
        }

    }
}
```

In the `Activity` I observe the `MutableLiveData` and react the changes to views, but it will throw an exception, because in Realm you cannot pass RealmObject between threads. I am wondering how do you manage that?

I know there are some workarounds.

One is to call `Realm.getDefaultInstance` in main thread, call `findAllAsync` to get `RealmResults`, and then register an listener to it to observe any changes and update the `MutableLiveData`.

Another solution is to to call `Realm.getDefaultInstance` in background thread, call `findAll` to get `RealmResults` and call `copyFromRealm`, passing it to `MutableLiveData`.

First solution might be better because second one will load data into memory?

However, my goal is to keep any Realm stuff in background if that is possible, please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, both of theses solutions that you gave are not suitable for android framework.

**The first solution**: Is bad because MainThread should not know and deal with Realm stuffs the MainThread is made for layout changes and android framework stuff's

**The second solutions**: Is bad because you are passing a data base model to your View ( that should not know anything about database ou remote database ).

**The Solution would be:**
Create an Object called UserModel, then in your ViewModel when you receive your users from DataBase read all these users and extract the values and create a list for UserModel an return these objects to View.

This is a good practice to separate the concepts because it's bad you have an database object full of Realm annotations and fields in your View, then separate the object that will only have the important values for View and will not have any database annotation. This way you have a clear responsability separations and will solve theses problem you are having.

It's importante to follow some DesignPatterns and the RepositoryPattern is a very nice one to solve some architectural problems, you can read mote about it here: https://proandroiddev.com/clean-architecture-data-flow-dependency-rule-615ffdd79e29

Hope it helps!